# Counter for build number in Azure Build Pipeline - Classic

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, ado, cicd

I am trying to get a dynamic build number based on some criteria in ADO build pipeline classic, not Yaml. I am facing an issue to have the build number incremental. Normally I used to refer $(Rev:r) under Option - build number format which automatically takes care of incremental numbers. since I have some custom logic written in Powershell to rename my build number, $(Rev:r) cannot be used in Powershell.

I got to know there is [counter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic%2Cpowershell#tabpanel_5_classic) but still unable to get that for my situation.

My Pattern is 1.0.1.1

the first portion is master release #
second one is minor release #
third one is defect fix #
last one is incremental